# find all data with group by in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

How to perform this query in mongoose 
i have found some example but i could not find solution for this

```
select * from table group by name
```

I have tried this

```
 table.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$name',                
            }
        }
    ], function (err, d) {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
        }
    });
```

But it shows only name not all data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this it should work

```
table.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$name',  //$region is the column name in collection
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the data

```
> db.tt.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a96dc8081f2fc07ecd7ffb"), "name" : "test", "numbers" : [ 7
6.3922, 42.9196154, ObjectId("56aea43cb6be380000616b07"), 789.11 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a96dee081f2fc07ecd7ffc"), "name" : "test", "numbers" : [ 8
7.938547, 42.9196154 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a96e00081f2fc07ecd7ffd"), "name" : "test", "numbers" : [ 4
2.9196154, 87.938547 ] }
```

The `$group` includes other field with `<fieldName>: '$fieldName'` type as below.

```
> db.tt.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {name: '$name', numbers: '$numbers'}}}])
```

The results are

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "test", "numbers" : [ 76.3922, 42.9196154, ObjectId("56aea4
3cb6be380000616b07"), 789.11 ] } }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "test", "numbers" : [ 87.938547, 42.9196154 ] } }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "test", "numbers" : [ 42.9196154, 87.938547 ] } }
```